# Use jQuery Sibling to find top <th> in HTML table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an HTML table that has many hidden columns.  You can think of the columns as sets of 3.  The first two are hidden and the 3rd is viewable.  When you mouseover the 3rd, the first 2 in the set of 3 become viewable also.  I am trying to figure out how to select the top 2 `<th>` in the column where the mouseover is happening so I can use jQuery to change the html to add `colspan='3'` to both `<th>` so that they span across all 3 columns of the "set".

For example: Mousing Over any part of the 1st yellow column makes the 2 columns that were hidden before that column now viewable. "1000017" and "Potato Chips" would be what need selected so that I can then change their column span to 3 so they correctly cover the columns again.  My current code does not work correctly though and selects the whole "Item name" row instead.

**My question is: How can I fix my this.siblings jQuery line so that it only selects the appropriate `<th>` instead of the whole row.**

Please see snippet below:

```js
$('.yellowbr').hover(function() {
  var sel = $(this).index();
  $('tr').each(function(){
    $('td',this).slice(sel-3,sel-1).toggleClass('hidetd');
    $(this).siblings().first().toggleClass('light');
  })
})
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.yellowbr {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.hidetd {
    display:none;  
}

.light {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Item #</th>
    <th>100017</th>
    <th>100018</th>
    <th>100019</th>
    <th>100020</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Component</th>
    <th><u>Potato chips</u>
    </th>
    <th><u>butterfingers</u>
    </th>
    <th><u>Flat Pretzels</u>
    </th>
    <th><u>Milk Chocolate</u>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-03</th>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-04</th>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-05</th>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-06</th>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-07</th>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is how everything looks if no columns were hidden and all headings span="3" covering the correct columns.

```css
.yellowbr {
  background-color: yellow;
}

table,th, td {
  
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
       
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Item #</th>
    <th colspan="3">100017</th>
    <th colspan="3">100018</th>
    <th colspan="3">100019</th>
    <th colspan="3">100020</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Component</th>
    <th colspan="3"><u>Potato chips</u></th>
    <th colspan="3"><u>butterfingers</u></th>
    <th colspan="3"><u>Flat Pretzels</u></th>
    <th colspan="3"><u>Milk Chocolate</u></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-03</th>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-04</th>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-05</th>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-06</th>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-07</th>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Select $('table').find('th:eq('+sel+')') is this what you are not looking for...can you be more clear what exactly should happen when you hover on any td

Comment: @Geeky Action only occurs when you mouseover a yellow column.  The 2 hidden columns before the yellow column you mouseover become visable.  The part I am looking for help is if you mouseover the 1st yellow column "chips" then needs to change to colspan="3".  I am trying to figure out how to select chips with jQuery.  If the 2nd yellow column is highlighted it would be butterfinger, so on and so forthe.

Comment: @Geeky currently my jQuery line chooses the whole row, I only want to choose the item that corresponds with the column with the mouseover though

Comment: can you explain more in detail I am having a hard time undestanding what you want done @Brandon

Comment: @RaniMorelesRubillos I edited my main post attempting to explain better.  I hope this helps.  The second snippet shows how things would look if nothing was hidden.  Basically I am trying to have the column that is getting the mouse over, opened like that, but all the others kept closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
$('.yellowbr').hover(function() {
  var sel = $(this).index();
  $('tr').each(function() {
    $('th', this).slice(sel / 3, sel / 3 + 1).attr('colspan', 3);
    $('th', this).filter(function(i) {
      return i !== sel / 3;
    }).attr('colspan', 1);

    var cellsToHightlight = $('td', this).slice(sel - 3, sel - 1);
    for (var i = 0; i < cellsToHightlight.length; i += 1) {
      var cell = $(cellsToHightlight[i]);
      if (cell.hasClass('hidetd')) {
        cell.removeClass('hidetd');
      }
    }

    $('td', this).filter(function(i, el) {
      return (i < sel - 3 || i > sel - 1) && (i + 1) % 3 !== 0;
    }).addClass('hidetd');

    $(this).siblings().first().toggleClass('light');
  });
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.yellowbr {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.hidetd {
  display: none;
}
.light {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Item #</th>
    <th>100017</th>
    <th>100018</th>
    <th>100019</th>
    <th>100020</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Component</th>
    <th><u>Potato chips</u>
    </th>
    <th><u>butterfingers</u>
    </th>
    <th><u>Flat Pretzels</u>
    </th>
    <th><u>Milk Chocolate</u>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-03</th>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-04</th>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-05</th>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-06</th>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-07</th>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='hidetd'>0</td>
    <td class='yellowbr'>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is perfect man!  Thanks so much!  Now to study the code to learn exactly what is going on there.  LoL